# VBA: application.onkey not working

Tags: vba, excel, keypress

I'm on VBA with an apparently simple code, trying to create an event triggered by pressing Enter.
So here is my code in the workbook:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnKey "", "pressEnter"

End Sub
```

And what should be happen in the module:

```
Public Sub pressEnter()

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = 20

End Sub
```

However, when I press Enter/Return key, nothing happens. Just as with a normal Enter, it selects the cell inferior to the active one. I tried with other keys, such as `^+b` or `^+a`, and I have the same problem.

Does someone see any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a key:

- For Enter on the numeric keypad use `Application.OnKey "{ENTER}", "pressEnter"`
- For the normal Enter use `Application.OnKey "~", "pressEnter"`

see [Application.OnKey Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx)

Be aware that other keys like `^+b` means <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. Make sure that `Public Sub pressEnter()` is in a **module** and not in `ThisWorkbook`. If it doesn't work in `Workbook_Open()` try `Workbook_Activate()` instead.

Comment: @Joliba Please mark this answer as solution, so other people can see that this question is solved.