# Application.onKey() callback procedure requirements

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA, there is an apparent requirement that a procedure associated with an Application.onKey() assignment be hosted in a module.  For example, in my worksheet code I have this assignment:

```
Application.OnKey Key:="{BS}" Procedure:="ClearCell.ClearFormatting"
```

and then in module ClearCell I have:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ClearFormatting()

  With Application.ActiveCell
    ...do some stuff
  End With
End Sub
```

There is a good answer at [VBA: application.onkey not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385854/vba-application-onkey-not-working) that advises one to move the code out of the workbook or worksheet and put it in a module.  The Microsoft documentation, however, does not mention this requirement at all!

My question is, why is there such a requirement and where is it documented?

Comment: There's no requirement like that?  `Procedure:="ThisWorkbook.SomeMethod"` should work fine.   Likewise if your method was in a worksheet module.

Comment: It certainly would not work from within the same worksheet.  Tried all sorts of different methods but no joy.

Comment: Would help to show exactly what you tried and describe what happened when you tried it.  It seems to work fine for me but obviously I'm just guessing at what you might be doing.

Comment: Sure!  Tried Procedure:="SomeMethod".  Did not work.  "ThisWorksheet.SomeMethod" did not work .  "Me.SomeMethod" did not work.  And that was with the code in the module as shown above in the worksheet.

Comment: What is happening is that I need to change the BG color of a cell based on a selection from a list, but as you know this can be bypassed by pressing the backspace or delete key.  Changing from the list is no problem through the Worksheet.Change event, but the backspace key only removes the text and does not trigger a change event.  So I am capturing the backspace key and processing the color change in my callback procedure.  Works great when I put in its own module.  There is more going on as I am computing a value based on two cells, each of which can be independently changed....

Comment: What kind of list?  A Data Validation drop down, or some other type?  If I hit backspace or delete on a cell with a DV list, it gets cleared and also raises a Change event.

Comment: What exactly happens with your code when it doesn't work?  Are you getting an error or ?

Comment: If I put `Application.OnKey Key:="{BS}", Procedure:="Sheet1.Test"` inside `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`, this works. It just calls `Sub Test()` underneath in the same worksheet module. Also, not sure if this was just a typo, but you're missing a comma in: `Application.OnKey Key:="{BS}" Procedure:="ClearCell.ClearFormatting"`.

Comment: I guess someone doesn't think I should ask a question about a problem I am having, after doing significant research and hitting a wall.  Not nice.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem.

[Microsoft Excel.Application.OnKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.OnKey)

> There is no way to currently detect the Command key in recent versions
> of Office VBA. Microsoft is aware of this and is looking into it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, ok. I found the same problem than described, the OnKey not functionning at all. I searched, I found this thread, and I also found later that Microsoft also knew this problem. I showed the Microsoft's  description and link.

Answer (score -1):

The code below assumes that special handling of <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to occur for a particular worksheet, `Sheet1` in this example. You can modify it to suit your needs. Here's the code-behind for `Sheet1`:

```
Option Explicit

' Turn on special handling of backspace key when Sheet1 is Activated
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' Either of these lines works
    Application.OnKey "{BS}", "Sheet1.BackSpaceKey"
    ' Application.OnKey "{BS}", "Module1.MyBackSpaceKey"
End Sub

' Turn off special handling of backspace key when Sheet1 is Deactivated
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.OnKey "{BS}"
End Sub

Private Sub BackSpaceKey()
    MsgBox "Backspace key get special handling from 'Sheet1.BackSpaceKey'.", vbOKOnly, "Test"
End Sub
```

Note the two options in `Worksheet_Activate`. The first one runs a sub that is located in `Sheet1`; the second (commented out) runs a sub in `Module1`. Both of these worked for me.

Here's the code in `Module1`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MyBackSpaceKey()
    MsgBox "Backspace key get special handling from 'Module1.MyBackSpaceKey'.", vbOKOnly, "Test"
End Sub
```